# Qgis: calculating distances for different types of lines for a report table

Tags: qgis

I have a Qgis project with lines classified in a field in 5 types. Composing a report, I need a table that shows the five types of line in the first column and in the second column the length for each type of line. No idea how to do this.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
CASE 
    WHEN  "Infra_class" = 0 THEN round ( sum ( "length","Infra_class" is '0') )
    WHEN  "Infra_class" = 1 THEN round ( sum ( "length","Infra_class" is '1') )
    WHEN  "Infra_class" = 2 THEN round ( sum ( "length","Infra_class" is '2') )
    WHEN  "Infra_class" = 3 THEN round ( sum ( "length","Infra_class" is '3') )
    ELSE round ( sum ( "length","Infra_class" is '4') )
END
```